# React-native: image is not rendered

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I am learning React native and simply want to add an image inside of a container.View and a title.Text. Nothing is being shown. I tried both accessing it from the assets folder and via uri.

My assets folder is outside of the components folder.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'
import { Text, Image, View } from 'react-native'

import { MAGIC_API } from './reusable/urls';


export const MagicAnswerList = () => {
  const [magicAnswer, setMagicAnswer] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
    fetch(MAGIC_API)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(magicdata => setMagicAnswer(magicdata))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }, [])

 return (
    <Container>
        <Title>
          {magicAnswer.Answer}
          <MagicBall 
            source={require('../assets/billiard.png')}
          /> 
        </Title>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your `<Image />` being used. I see `<MagicBall />` instead. I suggest you try rendering something simpler and see what happens.

Comment: I changed it to <Image /> and it is the same, I don't get any error message, but also nothing is being rendered.

Comment: The image is shown in the Inspector tool but does not render in the browser window

Comment: it renders on android

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `style` param to your `<Image />` tag. For example:

```
<Image
    source={require('../assets/billiard.png')}
    style={{
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        resizeMode: 'contain'
    }}
/>
```

Note that the `width` and `height` params are necessary to make it visible.

Comment: I have this above: `const MagicBall = styled.Image`
  width: 40px,
  height: 40px,
  border-radius: 35%,
`; `